# How to conditionally assign Ruby variables to object instances

Tags: ruby

I have a `Team` class that contains a `find_team` class method. The method returns a `Team` object if one is found, or `nil` if no object is found:

```
class Team
  @@all_teams = []

  def self.find_team(name)
    index = @@all_teams.find_index { |t| t.name == name }

    if index.nil?
      nil
    else
      @@all_teams[index]
    end
  end
end
```

In implementing the class, I need to assign a variable to the correct `Team` object if it exists or create a new `Team` object if it doesn't. I'm struggling with finding the clearest, quickest, *ruby-ist* way to do it. Some options I've considered:

```
t1 = Team.find_team("Some Team") ? Team.find_team("Some Team") : Team.new("Some Team")

t2 = Team.find_team("Some Other Team")
t2 ||= Team.new("Some Other Team")

t3 = if Team.find_team("Another Team")
       Team.find_team("Another Team")
     else
       Team.new("Another Team")
```

I favor the second example, as it's less verbose and repetitive, but I'm wondering if there's some Ruby trick I'm missing in this scenario.

Comment: For future reference and Google, this is called the singleton pattern.

Comment: I'm aware that Team.find_teams is a singleton method, but that class has plenty of instance methods as well. There's nothing about this question that's really particular to singleton methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t1 = Team.find_team("Some Team") || Team.new("Some Team")
```

is probably the most Ruby-ish version. You can also consider to enhance your custom method.

As a side note, you can refactor your `find_team` method to use `Enumerable#find`

```
class Team
  @@all_teams = []

  def self.find_team(name)
    @@all_teams.find { |t| t.name == name }
  end
end
```

And you can also add a new method that returns the instance if none

```
class Team
  @@all_teams = []

  def self.find_team(name)
    @@all_teams.find { |t| t.name == name }
  end

  def self.find_or_build_team(name)
    find_team(name) || Team.new(name)
  end
end
```

so that you will just call

```
Team.find_or_build("Some Team")
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
t1 = Team.find_team('Some Team') || Team.new('Some Team')
```

This assigns a new `Team` instance into `t1` only if `find_team` method returns `nil`.